# How can I export UITableViewCell into image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, printscreen

I need to export UITableViewCell into an image PNG or anything so I can send it as a print screen image embedded in email body using the MFMailComposerViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)captureCell {

    //hide controls if needed
CGRect rect = [yourTableCell bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [yourTableCell.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these methods. Just call `UIImage *image = [cell screenshot];`

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot
{
    return [self screenshotForRect:self.bounds];
}

- (UIImage *)screenshotForRect:(CGRect) rect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *anImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    return anImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like that:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourTableViewCellView.bounds.size);
[yourTableViewCellView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and then you can save the image to data :)